# How do I configure VisualStudio to use Git for some projects and TFVC for others?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs

Our main projects are moved to Git but the others are still on TFVC. How can I use both as appropriate?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem? Just use both... TFS support both Git and TFVC..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS>=2012 detect automatically a solution managed with git due to the '.git' folder containing all the git data.

I don't remember how it detects also projects managed with TFVC but I'm pretty sure it do it successfully (perhaps detecting '.vsscc' files and the server mapping)

But there is no problem. Just open your solution and all should be good.

Comment: It looks like rebooting got this all to work. So yes, it can just do this. But you may need to reboot after first changing the VCS for a project.